Why does a white rectangle appear behind the Google button when using Bootstrap's dark theme?
I am facing an issue with integrating the Google button. When using Bootstrap's dark theme (data-bs-theme="dark"), a white background appears behind the Google button. However, this does not happen with the light theme (data-bs-theme="light"). If I set the theme to white and then change it to dark using the inspector tool on the site, everything works properly.
package versions
react@18.3.1
@react-oauth/google@0.12.1
react-bootstrap@2.10.4
bootstrap@5.3.3
// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="dark">
  <body>
    <div id="root" class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column" style="background: gray;"></div>
  </body>
</html>

// App.js
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { GoogleLogin, GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';

function App() {
    return (
        <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="">
            <GoogleLogin
                onSuccess={''}
                onError={() => console.error('Login Failed')}
                theme="filled_black"
            />
        </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

When using a dark theme

When using a light theme


seeing as @react-oauth/google@0.12.1 is not an offical google package and it hasnt been updated in over two years i think you would be better off asking the developer in question.   github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth  TBH as google has recently updated their auth system i would be surprised if it even works.

Despite the fact that the library was updated 2 years ago, it works properly. But the real reason was the bootstrap color scheme, and after I changed the 'colorScheme' everything started working properly.
code


`code`